# jquery validator addmethod custom message

Tags: jquery, validation

I've created a method for jquery's validator plugin, that works like the remote rule.  The difference is that I'd like to display a dynamic error message (based on the ajax response).

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("duplicate", function(value, element, params) { 
    var object_settings = this.settings;
    params.data[$(element).attr("name")] = value;
    $.post(params.url, params.data, function(response) {
        if (response == 'true'){ return true; }
        else {
            object_settings.messages[element.name] = response;
            return false;
        }
    }, 'text');
}, '');
```

It works...sort of....it sets the message, but doesn't display it initially (if you validate the field a second time, the message is displayed).

Any suggestions?

(maybe the remote rule offers this functionality...I couldn't find anything in the documentation)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the solution....needed to call the showErrors function of the object:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("duplicate", function(value, element, params) { 
    var validator = this;
    params.data[element.name] = value;
    $.post(params.url, params.data, function(response) {
        if (response == 'true'){ return true; }
        else {
            var errors = {};
            errors[element.name] =  response;
            validator.showErrors(errors);
            return false;
        }
    }, 'text');
}, '');
```

Taken from "remote" in jquery.validate.js (lines 917 - 919)

Comment: The default error message is over writing the custom message, when I do this.

Answer (score 11):

I have followed the process mentioned in the site http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/15/37923/#comment-125774 and succeeded.

You have to call the method with the dynamic message, so that it will display that message. For example

```
$.validator.addMethod("validatePremium", function(value, element, param) {

    if( Condition )    

     {
       $.validator.messages.validatePremium = "your message here";
       //enter code here
       //...
       return false;
     }

    }, $.validator.messages.validatePremium);
```

Comment: Best answer for me, solve my issue with a charm: Link : https://codepen.io/plasebo/pen/VGaQam   
Thanks Kiran

Answer (score 9):

Was looking for solution to this as well, and found this...

In the original example, if you change this line:

```
object_settings.messages[element.name] = response;
```

To this:

```
$.validator.messages.duplicate = response;
```

This works for me. I found it here:
http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/15/37923/

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me

```
var errorMsg = '', $valid = false;
$.validator.addMethod("methodName",function(val, elem){
   $.ajax({
      url:'your_script.php',
      type:"POST",
      dataType:"json",
      data : {},
      success:function(response){
         if(response.success == false){
            errorMsg = response.msg;
            $valid = response.success;
         }
         else{
            $valid = true;
         }
      }
   });
   $.validator.messages["methodName"] = errorMsg;
   return $valid;
},'');
```

make sure to replace "***methodName***" with your method name
in this case "duplicate" in both places(addMethod function 1st arg and in the addMethod function body $.validator.messages["methodName"])

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the error message per validation method and per element, just as the plugin says:

```
// Adding validation method
$.validator.addMethod('sampleminimum', function (val, element, params) {
    return this.optional(element) || $(element).val() > params.min;
}, function(params, element) {
   return 'The field value cannot be less than %1'.replace('%1', params.min);
});

// Using validation
$(form).validate({
    rules: {
        'elementName': {
            sampleminimum: {min: 10}
        }
    }
});
```