# jQuery validation regex: multiple rule checks, same field

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have a jQuery validation regex that checks if phrase(s) are included:

```
$.validator.addMethod("regex", function(value, element, regexp) {
    return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
}, "You must include the required keyword phrase(s).");
```

If I have multiple phrases to check, i'm adding them with:

```
$("#text").rules("add", { regex: /phrase one/i });
$("#text").rules("add", { regex: /another phrase/i });
$("#text").rules("add", { regex: /test phrase/i });
```

The problem i'm having is that it only checks for the last phrase rule, meaning if "test phrase" is included, but the others aren't, it will accept it. I need it to check to make sure all phrases are included.

I would also like the error message to be able to include the phase that's missing, example, if "another phrase" is missing, the error will be:

> You must include the required phrase: another phrase

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You should make a method specific to the requirement, rather than going for the generic regex:

```
var vInstance = $("form").validator(/* options */);

$.validator.addMethod("multiPhrases", function (value, element, phrases) {
   var missingPhrase, errObject = {};

   // Check for all the phrases
   for (var i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
      if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(phrases[i].toLowerCase()) < 0) {
         // Phrase not found
         missingPhrase = phrases[i];
         break;
      }
   }

   // Show the error yourself
   if (missingPhrase) {
      errObject[$(element).attr("name")] =
         "You must include the required phrase: " +
         missingPhrase;
      vInstance.showErrors(errObject);
   }

   // Tell the plugin if there was an error
   return (missingPhrase == false);
});
```

This requires your input to have a name attribute, and you need to save a reference to the validator object (`vInstance`) when it's created. It's the best hack I can think of after looking at jQuery validator's API. IMO, a decent validation plugin should let you return a custom error message from the custom function...

Use it like so:

```
$("#text").rules("add", {multiPhrases: [
   "phrase one",
   "another phrase",
   "test phrase"
]});
```

Comment: I guess i'll give this a try since there are no better answers. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the error: "Warning: No message defined for article_text". Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the plugin wants you to put a specific error message in for the method. I could be wrong, but it looks like the plugin isn't flexible enough to allow dynamic error messages. What you can try is to add a message after the function in `addMethod` like you did for the regex (that'll get rid of the warning message), but my guess is that it'll override the one I tried to put in.

Comment: I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/976384/jquery-validator-addmethod-custom-message 

Maybe the showErrors() option will work?

Comment: I have that in my code above ;) - looks like they just set a redundant error message as the last argument in the `addMethod` function. Try that.

Comment: Well it does display the redundant/standard error message now, but the custom one is never displayed. It does check for the keywords, so at least that's working right. Good enough i suppose, unless you have any other ideas to try.

Comment: Interesting, not sure if it'll help - http://forum.jquery.com/topic/validation-plugin-changing-message-with-addmethod

Comment: That forum post just confirms my suspicions, although I did just think of a hack you can try... wrap the `vInstance.showErrors` line in a setTimeout for 100 milliseconds or so. Not elegant, but might work. I've been thinking about polishing up and releasing a validation framework I wrote a while back because sadly this one and jQuery Tool's one both aren't nearly flexible enough...

Answer (score 0):

I used Box9 answer, and fixed the problem him and Ricky were having about the message being overwritten with "Warning: No message defined for..."
So the complete and working solution would be this:

Quoting Box9:

You should make a method specific to the requirement, rather than going for the generic regex:

```
$("form").validator(/* options */);

$.validator.addMethod("multiPhrases", function (value, element, phrases) {
  var missingPhrase, errObject = {};

  // Check for all the phrases
  for (var i = 0; i < phrases.length; i++) {
    if (value.toLowerCase().indexOf(phrases[i].toLowerCase()) < 0) {
       // Phrase not found
       missingPhrase = phrases[i];
       break;
    }
  }

  // Set the message as default for this validation
  if (missingPhrase) {
    errObject["multiPhrases"] =
        "You must include the required phrase: " + missingPhrase;
     jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, errObject);
  }

  // Tell the plugin if there was an error
  return (missingPhrase == false);
});
```

Instead of showing the error yourself, as Box9 initially proposed with showErrors(), you must set it as the default message for this validation, because jQuery.validation plugin will look for the default anyway, and overwrite any previous error shown for this element.

Quoting Box9 again:

This requires your input to have a name attribute.

Use it like so:

```
$("#text").rules("add", {multiPhrases: [
   "phrase one",
   "another phrase",
   "test phrase"
]});
```

Thank you [Box9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405143/box9) and [Ricky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112796/ricky) for initially posting this, as it helped me find the solution.